# KivyMD: What's the best way to input only numbers in MDTextField?

Tags: python, input, kivy

I want to be able to type only numbers in the input field and I tried input_type but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. At least on PC... I did:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    padding: "10dp"

    MDTextField:
        id: text_field_error
        hint_text: "Helper text on error (press 'Enter')"
        helper_text: "There will always be a mistake"
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
        input_type: 'number'
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def build(self):
        self.screen.ids.text_field_error.bind(
            on_text_validate=self.set_error_message,
            on_focus=self.set_error_message,
        )
        return self.screen

    def set_error_message(self, instance_textfield):
        self.screen.ids.text_field_error.error = True


Test().run()
```

but it did nothing. I instead did:

```
def on_text(self, instance, text):
    if len(self.text) > 0:
            try:
                int(self.text)
                print('yayy int')
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    float(self.text)
                    print('yayy float')
                except ValueError:
                    print('Wait a minute... what are you?')
                    list_it = list(self.text)
                    list_it[-1] = ''
                    self.text = "".join(list_it)
```

but I would like to know if there's a simpler way. . .

Comment: Try using `input_filter: 'int'` in your `kv`.

Comment: Oh... I don't know how I missed that in the docs... Thank!

Comment: That is documented in the kivy `TextInput` documentation, and since `MDTextField` extends `TextInput` (via another intermediate class), it applies here.